# second and first derivative growth function

Tags: derivatives

I have a function I would like to take the first and second derivative from

$$f(t)= a\left(1-\frac{1}{1+(b(t+i))^e+(c(t+i))^f+(d(t+i))^h)}\right)$$

I have taken the following steps

$$u(t)={\left(\mathrm{b}\, \left(\mathrm{i} + t\right)\right)}^{\mathrm{e}} + {\left(\mathrm{c}\, \left(\mathrm{i} + t\right)\right)}^{\mathrm{f}} + {\left(\mathrm{d}\, \left(\mathrm{i} + t\right)\right)}^{\mathrm{h}} + 1$$

$f(t) = a (1-1/u(t))$
$f(t) = a ((u(t)-1)/u(t))$

```
for simplicity u(t) = u and f(t)=f
```

f= a*(u-1)/u

```
quotient rule
dy = d(u-1)
```

df = a*((du*u-du*(u-1))/u^2)

df = a * du/u^2

```
quotient rule
```

d2f = a*((d2u*u^2-du*d(u^2))/u^4)

### Is the above reasoning correct?

df= (a*(b*e*(b*(i + t))^(e - 1) + c*f*(c*(i + t))^(f - 1) + d*h*(d*(i + t))^(h - 1)))/((b*(i + t))^e + (c*(i + t))^f + (d*(i + t))^h + 1)^2

d2f=(a*((b^2*e*(e - 1)*(b*(i + t))^(e - 2) + c^2*f*(f - 1)*(c*(i + t))^(f - 2) + d^2*h*(h - 1)*(d*(i + t))^(h - 2))*((b*(i + t))^e + (c*(i + t))^f + (d*(i + t))^h + 1)^2 - (2*(b*e*(b*(i + t))^(e - 1) + c*f*(c*(i + t))^(f - 1) + d*h*(d*(i + t))^(h - 1))^2 + 2*(b^2*e*(e - 1)*(b*(i + t))^(e - 2) + c^2*f*(f - 1)*(c*(i + t))^(f - 2) + d^2*h*(h - 1)*(d*(i + t))^(h - 2))*((b*(i + t))^e + (c*(i + t))^f + (d*(i + t))^h + 1))*(b*e*(b*(i + t))^(e - 1) + c*f*(c*(i + t))^(f - 1) + d*h*(d*(i + t))^(h - 1))))/((b*(i + t))^e + (c*(i + t))^f + (d*(i + t))^h + 1)^4

---

$\dfrac{d}{dt} f(t) = \frac{a\, \left(b\, e\, {\left(b\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{e - 1} + c\, f\, {\left(c\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{f - 1} + d\, h\, {\left(d\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{h - 1}\right)}{{\left({\left(b\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^e + {\left(c\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^f + {\left(d\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^h + 1\right)}^2}$

$\dfrac{d2}{d2t} f(t) =\frac{a\, \left(\left(b^2\, e\, \left(e - 1\right)\, {\left(b\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{e - 2} + c^2\, f\, \left(f - 1\right)\, {\left(c\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{f - 2} + d^2\, h\, \left(h - 1\right)\, {\left(d\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{h - 2}\right)\, {\left({\left(b\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^e + {\left(c\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^f + {\left(d\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^h + 1\right)}^2 - \left(2\, {\left(b\, e\, {\left(b\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{e - 1} + c\, f\, {\left(c\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{f - 1} + d\, h\, {\left(d\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{h - 1}\right)}^2 + 2\, \left(b^2\, e\, \left(e - 1\right)\, {\left(b\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{e - 2} + c^2\, f\, \left(f - 1\right)\, {\left(c\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{f - 2} + d^2\, h\, \left(h - 1\right)\, {\left(d\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{h - 2}\right)\, \left({\left(b\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^e + {\left(c\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^f + {\left(d\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^h + 1\right)\right)\, \left(b\, e\, {\left(b\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{e - 1} + c\, f\, {\left(c\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{f - 1} + d\, h\, {\left(d\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^{h - 1}\right)\right)}{{\left({\left(b\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^e + {\left(c\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^f + {\left(d\, \left(i + t\right)\right)}^h + 1\right)}^4}$

Comment: This is very difficult to read. Are the m's constants and the this is a function of $t$ only?

Comment: yes the m's are all constant and the function is only dependent on t. The m's differ for every individual.

Comment: This is not very difficult to read, it is impossible! Please, try to find some $\TeX$ editor to do the work for you. I don't think anyone is brave enough to "reverse code" this.

Comment: @NielsDeBlende: Please check that I wrote $f(t)$ properly in my response.

Comment: sorry for all the horrible code. 
I've tried to convert it into latex by using the latexs command in matlab. However if i paste it here it doesn't really give what I want. If anyone can tell me what I've done wrong that would be great. Thanks (the latex? code is below)

Comment: @NielsDeBlende would you look at the first equation and see if my correction is what you intended? You seemed to have forgotten some parenthesis so it made it a little hard to parse.

Comment: the first equation is indeed correct, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m1 = a, m2 = b, m3 = c, m4 = d , m5 = e, m6 = f, m7 = h, m8 = i$.

$\dfrac{d}{dt} f(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt}\left[(a (1-1/(1+(b (t+i))^e+(c (t+i))^f+(d (t+i))^h)))\right] = \dfrac{(a (e (b (i+t))^e+f (c (i+t))^f+h (d (i+t))^h))}{((i+t) ((b (i+t))^e+(c (i+t))^f+(d (i+t))^h+1)^2)}$

$\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} f(t) = \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} \left[(a (1-1/(1+(b (t+i))^e+(c (t+i))^f+(d (t+i))^h)))\right] = a\left[\dfrac{ ((b^2 (e-1) e (b (i+t))^{e-2}+c^2 (f-1) f (c (i+t))^{f-2}+d^2 (h-1) h (d (i+t))^{h-2})}{\left((b (i+t))^e+(c (i+t))^f+(d (i+t))^h+1\right)^2-\dfrac{2 (b e (b (i+t))^{e-1}+c f (c (i+t))^{f-1}+d h (d (i+t))^{h-1})^2}{\left((b (i+t))^e+(c (i+t))^f+(d (i+t))^h+1\right)^3}}\right]$

**Update**

If we write, $f(t) = a\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{u(t)}\right)$, then, by the quotient rule, we have:

$$f'(t) = a\left(0 - \dfrac{0 - u'(t) \cdot 1}{u^2(t)}\right) = a\dfrac{u'(t)}{u^2(t)}$$

Comment: + I saw this earlier...good to have posted a great answer (what a monster to format, with all the parentheses and bracktets, not to mention the fraction.

Comment: 10000 times thanks. I couldn't do it. Does my reasoning to get to this formula stands?

Comment: @NielsDeBlende: I think you should use the approach I showed (making all those variable names easier and then find the first derivative and validate what I got. Currently, your approach is not looking correct to me, but it may be algebra related and I cannot read it. If you have issues doing my approach, please report back. Regards

Comment: It's a growth function. I'm a biology student (that's why the ugly math and the unawareness of latex). Atm I'm trying to convert the formula into latex context

Comment: @NielsDeBlende: Are you trying to use my approach? At the end, you can substitute back all the original variable names you had as they make things very messy with derivatives. Regards

Comment: I've tried to use your approach. It's very helpfull. d2f is not how it should be but it is in latex formation.

Comment: thanks a lot. If i compare both df's in your and mine df equation it seems to look the same.

Comment: @NielsDeBlende: Excellent! Now, work on the second part (which is the same approach, but a lot more ugly algebra). Good luck! Regards